# simpli get view from custom view in esspresso android

Tags: android, testing, kotlin, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have a Custom component in android with this layout.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

when using in another layout I find editText by this code.(Espresso)

```
val editText = onView(
        allOf(withId(R.id.editText)
               , isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.mainLayout))
               , isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.mobileEdt))
        )
)
```

I use this custom Component in all app and many layouts.
can I minify or convert to function in my app for doesn't write again and again?

Maybe I change the component layout, so I have to edit all withId in all test.

Answer (score 0):

Your component has probably a class name. Let's say `CustomEditText`.
In that case you can implement a `BoundedMatcher` based custom matcher, which makes sure that it will only match view instances of your `CustomEditText`.

Simple implementation could look like this:

```
fun customEditWithId(idMatcher: Matcher<Int>): Matcher<View> {

    return object : BoundedMatcher<View, CustomEditText>(CustomEditText::class.java!!) {

        override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
            description.appendText("with id: ")
            idMatcher.describeTo(description)
        }

        override fun matchesSafely(textView: CustomEditText): Boolean {
            return idMatcher.matches(textView.id)
        }
    }
}
```

then your assertion looks like this:

```
onView(customEditWithId(0)).perform(click());
```

Answer (score 0):

it's obviously not a descendant of `R.id.mobileEdt` ...

```
val editText = onView(allOf(
    withId(R.id.editText),
    isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.mainLayout))
))
```